# Is there a site with preparation ideas for opening tabiyas?

Tags: opening, websites

I deal with this problem every time. I have some 'default' repertoire and when preparing against concrete opponent, I find that it is highly probable we will reach some concrete well known position and I want be the one to come with system he can't expect me to play. Ok I can use book, engine, games to create interesting system myself, but it takes soooo much time. People already made thousands of preparations like this, coming with a sharp forcing idea hard to refute over the board, playing new move with completely different approach compared to main lines... Is there somewhere something like market of these ideas? Just pgn with 20 lines, for example. Or text. Anything that is good for titled players, computer checked lines, dangerous surprises for one game etc.

Comment: Opening Encyclopedia like Informant? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings)

Comment: I think it is not what I am looking for. They rely I guess a lot on main lines while in a preparation you have different goals. Surprise, maximize winning chances, maximize drawing chances, go to endgame, go dynamic. And lines should be prepared to fit this too.

Comment: How is it you are asking this question when your profile says: "CAREER: Professional chess player with rating over 2500, grandmaster since 2014."

???

It's baffling...

Comment: This is no common knowledge what I'm asking. At least I think so :D There is no big difference between playing with the best preparation ever and with no preparation at all. You miss your preparation almost always anyway and you mainly need playing abilities. Even if you succeed in home preparation, what is it worth? 20 minutes and 20 centipawns? This is just small part of the game.

Comment: Nice question - if there's something like this out there, I'd also like to know :) By the name, the "Dangerous Weapons" series by Everyman Chess suggests it tries to do this, but having looked at some of those chapters I'm not really convinced of their value.

Comment: If you feel the need to change to another system instead of your default repertoire every time you prepare, wouldn't the time be better spent improving your default repertoire?

Comment: Things like Chess Publishing, the short-lived Chessvibes opening bulletin, NIC Yearbook, Chessbase bulletin, Informator etc all leave much of the work to you, and they're public so the opponent probably has them too.

Comment: So I'm afraid the answer will be "pay for seconds" for rich top players and _share your ideas within a group of friends_ for others.

Comment: @hoacin What I find the most useful is using ChessBase 14 with a large games database, using the "prepare against opponent" feature of CB14 to easily get an idea of your opponent's repertoire, and then use an opening book together with an engine to find surprising, not so often tried sidelines. It involves some manual labour, but it's been worth it for me so far, almost always being "in book" longer than my opponents.

Answer (score 1):

The SOS ("Secrets of Opening Surprises") books and articles (in New in Chess magazine) can be good references.  Once in the USATW I was paired up against a 2450 rated player.  I found references with a quick online search that he played the Caro-Khan.  I walked in the bookstore and looked in an SOS book and found a line Kasparov used in blitz a lot.  After 10 minutes of preparation I was armed  to get my well booked opponent out of his element and I won my best game of the tournament.
I've done such things with the Chess Informants a lot including preparation against Yermolinsky in the US Open.  I would say Chess Informant is best if you have the time and money.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know you want a opening repertoire for positional or attacking one. I use to play mainly positional repertoire but for some blitz chooses attacking one. I followed some lectures of yassar serwain's from saint luis club , it is available in youtube . I also follow a pdf of gufeld's repertoire [Repertoire of Gufeld and another man](https://e-nautia.com/erich.g/disk/LIBROS%20DE%20AJEDREZ%20EN%20PDF/An_Opening_Repertoire_for_the_Positional_Player.pdf)

And also following some advice from GM Arthur Yusupov . But at last I must say that if you do not rely on your repertoire then you cannot become a good player , and if you do not make a hard work on your openings then you cannot make a solid typical opening (most of the player don't like this type of opening which has been analysed , like with 48 moves or more!! ) like Lev poluguasky (Pronouncing wrong?!) , His openings homework was great , every player was scared to play with him , he is mainly known for his hardwork on openings (his favorite opening was sicilian najdorf , and he invented the opening Sicilian Najdorf Poluguasky variation , which is sharp like axe ) , if you make a hardwork on your opening you can be one like him . And at one stage he said by this hard work attitude  he can prepare any master player into world champion.

Comment: And you can also find opening theories from Wikipedia and  www.thechesswebsite.com , thechessworld.com etc.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and some of your comments are pretty "dubious". Yes, having a solid opening repertoire is important, but you need to vary as well, and being the first to come up with a "novelty" in a game can be a great weapon in winning the game at high levels. Always playing the same lines means you are a sitting duck where any opponent can prepare whatever variation they want against you.

Comment: Yes , you are also correct , i am not saying you are totally wrong . But , recently i played a tournament , states level , where i recognized that a solid repertoire is most important , and by saying a solid repertoire , i am not only asking to learn only one side (like if you are playing , french , you not going to prepare only a line like tarrasch Nf6 line but you also have to prepare c5 , Nc6 line )  and also you have prepare the sidelines and the traps of that line as well , or you cannot remember the whole boring line (playing same thing everytime bores everyone).

Comment: It depends a lot on the level you're playing at. Once you reach a higher level (say 2200+), and many of your games are in online databases, people can prepare for you and so either you need to know *every* variation that can be thrown at you, or you need to vary your openings sufficiently that your opponent cannot easily choose a line to play against you for say the first 20 moves. The element of surprise is very important in openings, even more so than playing the objectively best moves.